# how to check how many images are in div with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, count

```
<div id="images">

                    <a href="resources/certified_training/1.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -1</a>
                    <a href="resources/certified_training/2.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -2</a>
                    <a href="resources/certified_training/3.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -3</a>
                    <a href="resources/certified_training/4.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -4</a>
                    <a href="resources/certified_training/5.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -5</a>


                </div>
```

i want to get number of images which are in this div. they are 5, and i want to read it with javascript or jquery..
how to do it????

Comment: There are no images in that div. There are `<a>` tags, but no `<img>`

Comment: Just use a matching selector for the wanted elements in that div, and then look at the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) of the returned jQuery object …

Comment: There are no images in that `div` - only 5 `a` elements

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preloading images with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can check `length` property. You can also pass selector to `.children()`

```
$("#images").children().length
```

or

```
$("#images").children('a').length
```

or

```
$("#images a").length
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EbGMM/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.has()` condition to check if the elements contain the `<img>` element:

```
$(function() {
    var imgCount = $("#images a").has("img").length;
});
```

If each `<a>` may contain more than one image though, you should use this instead:

```
$("#images a img").length
```

p/s: My answer is made on the assumption that OP intends to nest `<img>` within the `<a>` tags, i.e.:

```
<a href="resources/certified_training/2.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372"><img /></a>
```

---

If the OP is referring to counting the number of **linked** images, he can use:

```
$("a[href*='png']").length
```

Comment: None of the `a` tags have an `img` tag.

Comment: That is assuming that the OP means he has `<img>` nested in the `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Javascript only solution.

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('a').length);
                    OR
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('a').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of elements in a jQuery selection, use `length`.

```
$('#images a').length
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  alert($("#images a").length);
```

Or,

```
 alert($("#images").children("a").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$('#images a[rel^="shadowbox[certifiedtraining]"]').length // 5
```

This will only choose `<a>` elements which have a `rel` attribute starting with `"shadowbox[certifiedtraining]"`. For example, if you had this HTML:

```
<div id="images">
                <a href="http://google.com">google</a><br/>
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a><br/>

                <a href="resources/certified_training/1.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -1</a>
                <a href="resources/certified_training/2.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -2</a>
                <a href="resources/certified_training/3.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -3</a>
                <a href="resources/certified_training/4.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -4</a>
                <a href="resources/certified_training/5.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -5</a>


            </div>
```

It would still only return 5, because there are only 5 shadowbox images there.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KfmTf/)**

Answer (score 0):

So, let's go!

```
//if you want to count elements use .length property

$('#images a').length

//if you want to count images by name
var images = [ ".png", ".jpg", ".gif" ] //images types
var count = 0;


for(var a=0; a < $('#images a').length; a++)
{
    for(var b=0; b < images.length; b++)
    {

        if( $($('#images a')[a]).attr('href').indexOf(images[b]) !== -1 ) //indexOf returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1:
        {
            count++
        } 
    } 
}

alert(count);
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vw37C/)

Hope this help! :)